# static member variable allocation time

Tags: c++, templates

all

when this variable be c.value caculating?

compile time? or runtime?

```
template<int A, typename T>
struct foo
{
    static const T value = A + foo<A-1, T>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct foo < 0, T >
{
    static const T value = 0;
};

int main(void)
{

    foo<4, int> c;
    cout << c.value << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

it calculate the value recursively but this value is const so not change in runtime and then i think the caculation is ok on compile time.

is it right thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Because `A` is a template parameter, calculation of init value of `value` is done at compile time. `value` can be const or not for this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Formally, `A + foo<A-1, T>::value` is a compile-time evaluable constant expression.

`foo<4, int>` is indeed compile-time evaluable and so, therefore, is `value` for all the specialisations.

Without the `const`, the type would *still* be compile-time evaluable.